# Изменение части поля в таблице

Tags: sql-server

Есть поле типа varchar, необходимо изменить данные в нем. Примеры данных: 07010000001, 07010000002... Необходимо изменить только первые 4 символа с 0701 на 0707. В результате данные должны выглядеть так: 07070000001, 07070000002...

Вторая проблема: такое же поле, но с данными 09180000001, 09180000002...$, в результате данные должны выглядеть так: 18180000001, 18180000002...

Как в sql 2008 поменять часть поля, а не все поле целиком?

Answer (score 1):

Поменять можно только все поле целиком.
То, что вам нужно - это оператор REPLACE.

Comment: А что, разве нет в языке функции типа substr(...). Если есть, тогда можно

Comment: Есть такая функция. Но апдейтить часть поля все равно нельзя.

Comment: Как-то так. А?

    update t set v = '0707' + substr(v, 5, length(v) - 4) 
    where substr(v, 1, 4) = '0701'
    или where v like '0701%'

Comment: Да, похоже